# Visual Basic path asterisk

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to figure out how to replace a char with a (random) char in a path for example, so I don't need to check multiple times (Exemple : *:/Program Files/abc/*.cfg). In this exemple, it would delete all .cfg files in this folder on every disk drives.

What I've tried :

```
If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(Dir & "\abc\?\?.cfg") Then
        My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(Dir & "\abc\?\?.cfg")
End If
```

Comment: So you want a wildcard for disk drives?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I want, but it's not working with the code I've gave you

Comment: It is simply not how wildcards work, they are not regular expressions.  You must iterate the drives and directories yourself.  Disk drives are organized as trees, best iterated by recursive code.  Lots and lots examples around for that.

Comment: Could you give me a kind of link ? And by the way, I've found a solution for the drives, the only problem is for the others folders I could encounter. I need a solution just for the folders. Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to use a wildcard for a disk drive (at least I couldn't find any way to do it), but you can quite easily get all the drives on your computer and run a loop, using the [`DriveInfo.GetDrives`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.getdrives(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
For Each Drive As DriveInfo In DriveInfo.GetDrives()
    Dim FilePath As String = String.Format("{0}Test1.txt", Drive.Name)
    If File.Exists(FilePath) Then
        Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString("Exists: ") & FilePath)
    End If
Next
```

**update**
In order to use wildcards, you must use `Directory.GetDirectories` and `Directory.GetFiles` instead of `File.Exists`:

```
Dim WildcardPath As String = "abc\*"
Dim WildcardFileName As String = "*.cfg"
For Each Drive As DriveInfo In DriveInfo.GetDrives()
    Try
        Dim Dirs As String() = Directory.GetDirectories(Drive.Name, WildcardPath)
        For Each Dir As String In Dirs
            Dim Files As String() = Directory.GetFiles(Dir, WildcardFileName)
            For Each FileName As String In Files
                If File.Exists(FileName) Then
                    Console.WriteLine(FileName)
                End If
            Next
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
    End Try
Next
```

**Note:** you will get exceptions when attempting to read from the dvd drive if no disk is inside, and when attempting to find directories that doesn't exists (i.e if you have a `Z` drive and no `Z:\abc` directory you will get an exception "Could not find a part of the path `Z:\abc`").

Comment: But how do I use a wildcard for folders and file names ?

Comment: you can't use wildcards with file.exists, you will need to use Directory.GetDirectories and Directory.GetFiles instead. I'll edit my answer as soon as I will have a working example for you.

Comment: Thank's a lot, I'm waiting for this !

Comment: The thing is I already know the disk used (I've edited the first message, you can see the code, Dir is made of the MyDocuments directory). So it might be even easier, but still, I don't know how to do this..

Comment: If you need to search a known directory for sub directories that include a wildcard and files that includes wildcards, GetDirectory and GetFiles is the way to go. if it's something else please consider editing your question

Comment: Thank you I'm going to look for this. Thank you for all your help !